# Can I use "transform: rotate" and "background-size: cover" at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I am using `background-size: cover` and then some times I also use `transform: rotate` but that combination does not work together. It retains it's original cover size and not one that matches with the rotation.

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/vkfhxmLr/4/

Is there an HTML/CSS only solution? I need to avoid javascript.

[image]

Comment: a generic solution or for this particular case?

Comment: My real case is far more complicated but this particular case represents it well. Except I also use background-position percentages.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right (even in your case unexpected) behaviour because you are rotating the html element, not its background.

Possible solutions:

**1) Rotate the image in origin (server side):**

This requires manual (or automated) transformation over the original image and implies network overhead if different rotations are needed.

In a project of mine I use [pug templates](https://pugjs.org) (initially generated exporting static svg files) to generate parametized svg files where I can change any parameter I need from the url.

I'm not sure whether svg can be used as background-image (I guess not) but I have two express routes to fetch them: One that retrieves generated svg and another that converts (and caches) it to png through imagemagick.

**2) Rotate the contained image instead of the container:**

This is slightly more tricky and only works for 90degree rotation because you need to reverse dimensions and re-center the container (I added a `.rotated` class to handle it).

See [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tquw0zx9/):

```
.container.rotated {
  width:200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform: translate(50px, 0px);
}

.img2 {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

**3) Enlarge and rotate the contained image**

Same as before, but instead of switching dimensions and translating position of the container, just set it as `overflow: hidden;`. But in this case you will need to enlarge (and properly center) the contained div to ensure it covers all container's inner space.

Comment: Thankyou. #1 is what I want to avoid and is why I created the question. I will work on these two suggestions. Thanks!